# Open source duplicate image finder for Linux?

Tags: search, image-manipulation, images, duplicate

Is there a free and open source duplicate image finder for Linux based systems?

Finding exact duplicates (based on content, not file name) is sufficient for me, but the ability to find similar images would certainly be great, too.

Comment: DupeGuru has a specialized version for images. I post this as a comment because I never tried it.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

#### Digikam

Add all the photos to your collection. In the menu, select “Tools / Find duplicates”. This will look for duplicates accross your whole collection.

#### Findimagedupes

A command line tool. Pass all the images you want to compare on the command line.

#### Geeqie (formerly gqview)

In the menu, select “File / Find duplicate”. Drag and drop image files do the duplicates window. You can drop directories to add their contents recursively.

#### Fdupes

A command line tool to find byte-for-byte duplicates in a directory tree.

<sub>(Reposted from https://askubuntu.com/questions/4072/how-can-i-find-duplicate-photos)</sub>

Comment: `findimagedups` will also descend hierarchies, does not require byte-level duplication and (more importantly) can keep records to speed up future runs (because the initial pass over a large stash of images can take a *long* time).

Comment: I think jdupes (https://github.com/jbruchon/jdupes) would be a good update / addition to this list. It is based on fdupes but advertises speed and feature improvements.